# Как запустить двух ботов на одном токене? Pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Правильнее будет сказать, как запустить два разных кода для бота, но чтобы использовался один токен? Может существуют какие-то библиотеки? Или есть методы с использованием pytelegrambotapi?

Comment: Не совсем понял, это будут 2 разных бота или один бот, в котором есть 2 "кода", работающие отдельно друг от друга?
Если 2 бота-то это невозможно, на сколько я знаю

Comment: один токен - один бот. А в чем смысл вашей идеи?

Comment: невозможно, как я знаю, запустить два скрипта на один токен, произойдет ошибка пулинга, да и в общем будет плохо выглядеть это всё. По хорошему объединить код в один.

Comment: Будет 100% ошибка пуллинга, поэтому лучше разделить самого бота на модули